# In chrome dev tool footer element is not displayed while in firefox dev tool it is displayed. Why?

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I am developing a static web app via React.js. I am using the google dev tool to inspect elements. In responsive design mode, everything is fine. However, when I select a specific mobile phone the footer element is not shown when I scroll to the bottom. However, it is visible on the console when ı inspect elements I can see the HTML info. I thought that maybe somehow I fixed the height for mobile devices or smt. Then I tried the firefox dev tool and I am able to see the footer. I have no idea which one is more realistic since I didn't deploy it yet. I deleted the history of browser before I tried.

More specifically; on the chrome dev tool when I select responsive design mode and change the resolution to 375x812 (same as iPhone X), I am able to see my footer. If I select iPhone x rather than responsive design mode, then I don't see it. It is more annoying that, both cases are okay for the firefox tool and I see my footer. So what is the problem ? Why two dev tools act so so differently for the same app and more importantly which one is true ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. There is a zoom option next to the width and height. It was 100% for my case, which should be "fit to window". I am leaving this dumb question here, it helps if any other beginner faces the same issue.